# Can many (similar) processes use a common RAM cache?

Tags: caching, operating-system, multiprocessing, memcached

As I understand the creation of processes, every process has it's own space in RAM for it's heap, data, etc, which is allocated upon its creation. Many processes can share their data and storage space in some ways. But since terminating a process would erase its allocated memory(so also its caches), I was wondering if it is possible that many (similar) processes share a cache in memory that is not allocated to any specific process, so that it can be used even when these processes are terminated and other ones are created.
This is a theoretical question from a student perspective, so I am merely interested in the general sence of an operating system, without adding more functionality to them to achieve it.
For example I think of a webserver that uses only single-threaded processes (maybe due to lack of multi-threading support), so that most of the processes created do similar jobs, like retrieving a certain page.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, when a process is terminated the RAM clears it. However your right as things such as webpages will be stored in the Cache for when there re-called. For example -
You open Google and then go to another tab and close the open Google page, when you next go to Google it loads faster.

However, what I think your saying is if the Entire program E.G - Google Chrome or Safari - is closed, does the webpage you just had open stay in the cache? No, when the program is closed all its relative data is also terminated in order to fully close the program.

I guess this page has some info on it - 
https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory

Answer (score 0):

There are a least four ways what you describe can occur.

First, the system address space is shared by all processes. The Operating system can save data there that survives the death of a process.

Second, processes can map logical pages to the same physical page frame. The termination of one process does not cause the page frame to be deallocated to the other processes.

Third, some operating systems have support for writable shared libraries.

Fourth, memory mapped files.

There are probably others as well.